# python - installed package. Its installed, but not found

Tags: python, windows, pip

```
Win10
Python 3.8.2
latest anaconda download and updated everything
```

Hi,

I know, not again a problem which is discussed multiple times, but here I am not able to solve it.

short example:

```
pip install jsonmerge
python -c "import jsonmerge"
--> ModuleNotFoundError
```

I tried the same in a anaconda virtual enviroment like:

```
conda create -n test
activate test
pip install jsonmerge
python -c "import jsonmerge"
```

Same result.
I also found issues about pip in venv in anaconda. The fix says: install pip into the venv and then install the package which also didn't work.

The only thing that loads the package is the spyder IDE, it doesn't make sense.

Do I have a problem which my python installation (which I reinstalled already) or is the package faulty?

edit:

Got it working! I had to do a clean reinstall of python. Reinstalling Anaconda wasn't enough.
Search for every bit of python on your system until

```
where python
```

does give no results anymore

i also deleted

```
In the my documents folder:
.anaconda
.conda
.matplotlib
anaconda3


In the %appdata%\local folder:
pip

python.exe and python3.exe at
%appdata%\local\microsoft\windowsapps\
```

probably search for python and pip in typical folders like my documents, appdata/local,locallow and roaming, and delete every instance. Then with the fresh installation of anaconda it worked

Comment: Your `pip` and `python` commands must be using different versions of Python.  Show us the output of these commands: `pip --version` and `python --version`

Answer (score 0):

I've done exactly the same as your conda commands with python 3.8.13 and conda 4.14.0 and no problems. So if the package is faulty it's in a niche way.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your pip version is linked to a different python install.
Try running pip like this to make sure it's the right one:
`python -m pip install my_package`